# building a string out of a variable amount of arguments

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, printf

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdarg.h>


int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    char *arr[] = { "ab", "cd", "ef" };
    char **ptr, **p, *str;
    int num = 3;
    int size = 0;

    ptr = calloc(num, 4);
    p = ptr;

    for (; num > 0; num--)
            size += strlen(*(p++) = arr[num - 1]);

    str = calloc(1, ++size);
    sprintf(str, "%s%s%s", ptr[0], ptr[1], ptr[2]);

    printf("%s\n", str);

    return 0;
}
```

output: `"efcdab"` as expected.

now, this is all fine and suitable if the argument count to `sprintf` is predetermined and known. what i'm trying to achieve, however, is an elegant way of building a string if the argument count is variable (`ptr[any]`).

first problem: 2nd argument that is required to be passed to `sprintf` is `const char *format`.
second: the 3rd argument is the actual amount of passed on arguments in order to build the string based on the provided `format`.

how can i achieve something of the following:

`sprintf(str, "...", ...)`

basically, what if the function receives 4 (or more) char pointers out of which i want to build a whole string (currently, within the code provided above, there's only 3). that would mean, that the 2nd argument must be (at least) in the form of `"%s%s%s%s"`, followed by an argument list of `ptr[0], ptr[1], ptr[2], ptr[3]`.

how can make such a 'combined' call, to `sprintf` (or `vsprintf`), in the first place? things would be easier, if i could just provide a whole pointer array (**ptr) as the 3rd argument, instead.. but that does not seem to be feasible? at least, not in a way that `sprintf` would understand it, so it seems.. as it would need some special form of `format`.

ideas / suggestions?

Comment: The main problem seems to be that sprintf doesn't do what you want. Have you heard of `strcat`?

Comment: @karlphillip: that is why i mentioned 'elegant', string copying solutions rely on buffer manipulations. the whole point of asking this question was to evade this type of behavior and make use of some sort of 'grouping'.

Comment: I do have an answer for that... Switch to **C++** and use `std::string`!

Comment: But what you're doing here is technically also buffer manipulation, is it not? Your `str` variable is acting as the destination buffer here.

Comment: @JAB: let's not get into a semantics dispute. yes, of course it is. i think you have perfectly understood what i meant by that comment. if you have a better `term` for the goal that i have specified - i would be happy to hear it.

Answer (score 1):

karlphillip's suggestion of `strcat` does seem to be the solution here. Or rather, you'd more likely want to use something like `strncat` (though if you're working with a C library that supports it, I'd recommend `strlcat`, which, in my opinion, is much better than `strncat`).

So, rather than `sprintf(str, "%s%s%s", ptr[0], ptr[1], ptr[2]);`, you could do something like this:

```
int i;

for (i = 0; i < any; i++)
    strncat(str, arr[i], size - strlen(str) - 1);
```

(Or `strlcat(str, arr[i], size);`; the nice thing about `strlcat` is that its return value will indicate how many bytes are needed for reallocation if the destination buffer is too small, but it's not a standard C function and a lot of systems don't support it.)

Comment: half the `string.h` can be a solution here. however, i'm not sure how much value will this hold. as i have deliberately disregarded this approach, hoping that there'd be a better way. i think, i can manage on my own with `strcat`, though. let me know if something comes up and you find a better way ;)

Comment: You could always create a function library of your own that supports segmented strings and ignore actual concatenation. But that seems to me to be at least as much overkill as, if not more overkill than, switching to C++.

Answer (score 0):

There's no other way to do this in **C** without manipulating buffers.

You could, however, switch to **C++** and use the fabulous `std::string` to make your life easier.

Comment: or people could refrain from adding pointless and useless comments as major as switching to something else. however, thank you for the other part of the comment, if this holds true and is really not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Your first problem is handled by: `const char *` is for the function, not you. Put together your own string -- that signature just means that the function won't change it.

Your second problem is handled by: pass in your own va_list. How do you get it? Make your own varargs function:

```
char *assemble_strings(int count, ...)
{
    va_list data_list;
    va_list len_list;
    int size;
    char *arg;
    char *formatstr;
    char *str;
    int i;

    va_start(len_list, count);
    for (i = 0, size = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        arg = va_arg(len_list, char *);
        size += strlen(arg);
    }
    va_end(len_list);

    formatstr = malloc(2*count + 1);
    formatstr[2*count] = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        formatstr[2*i] = '%';
        formatstr[2*i+1] = 's';
    }
    str = malloc(size + 1);

    va_start(data_list, count);
    vsprintf(str, formatstr, data_list);
    va_end(data_list);

    free(formatstr);

    return(str);
}
```

You'll need some way to terminate the varargs, of course, and it's much easier to just pass it to vsprintf if the string list is entirely within the varargs -- since standard C requires at least one regular argument.

Answer (score 0):

The loop I would use for the final copy into str would be something like:

```
for(i=0, p=str; i < num; i++)
    p += sprintf(p, "%s", ptr[i]);
```

or

```
for(i=0, p=str; i < num; i++)
    p += strlen(strcpy(p, ptr[i]));
```

rather than trying to deal with a variable number of arguments in a single call to sprintf.